# Segmentation fault on homework. Can't figure out why

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm having trouble figuring out the cause for a seg fault. I've debugged in GDB and it tells me the line that is giving me trouble, but I still can't figure it out.

```
Employee* readfile(FILE* file) {
  Employee* newemployee;
  char* tempsalary;
  int salary;
  char* name;
  char* dept;
  char line[128];
  while(file != NULL) {
    fgets(name, sizeof(line), file);
    newemployee->name = strdup(name);  // THIS IS WHERE THE SEGFAULT IS
    fgets(dept, sizeof(line), file);
    newemployee->department = strdup(dept);
    fgets(tempsalary, sizeof(line), file);
    sscanf(tempsalary, "%d", &salary);
    newemployee->salary = salary;
  }
  return newemployee;
```

The main program that I'm trying to run it in is supposed to open the file, read the lines and create an Employee struct out of it. It prints the structs using a previous function.

```
int main() {
  FILE* file;
  file = fopen ("stest2.txt", "r");
  Employee* employees[max_employees];
  int i;
  int c;

  for (i = 0; i < max_employees; i++) {
    employees[i] = readfile(file);
    printEmployee(employees[i]);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems you have a typo, Did you mean:

```
fgets(name, sizeof(line), file);
```

to be:

```
fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);
```

---

Also,

```
Employee* newemployee;
newemployee->name = strdup(name);
```

You just dereferenced a uninitialized pointer resulting in **Undefined Behavior**.
`newemployee` needs to point to a memory big enough to hold a `Employee` object before it can be dereferenced.

```
Employee* newemployee;
Employee emp;
newemployee = &emp;
newemployee->name = strdup(name);
```

---

Both the above mentioned problems are replicated throughout your code. You need to fix that.

Comment: I fixed the problem that was causing the seg fault, but now the program is running without ever printing results and ending. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

No memory has been allocated for `name`. So

```
fgets(name, sizeof(line), file);
```

is likely to be the issue that manifests later.

Allocate memory for `name` before reading lines into it.

Comment: Also newemployee and tempsalary.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the segfault. Now I need to figure out why the program never ends.

Comment: You have to change your condition in the while loop.  `while(file != NULL)` is always true once file is opened successfully.

Comment: Wow I should've seen that! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

None of your pointers appear  to have allocated memory.  NewEmployee, Dept, name, tmpsalary.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring "newemployee" as a pointer to an instance of the Employee class, but you never actually allocate a new Employee. In C++, the following two calls are usually equivalent (unless you are using operator overloading, which in this case you're not):

```
newemployee->name = "hello";
(*newemployee).name = "hello";
```

Since you never assigned anything to the "newemployee" pointer, you end up dereferencing a completely random memory location, which does not belong to your process, and thus your operating system kills it right away -- by signaling a segfault.